# htaccess - Redirect to subfolder without changing browser URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've a domain that contains a subfolder with the web app structure. I added a `.htaccess` on my root domain to point the public folder on my subfolder web app. It works fine, but when I type `www.example.com` the browser URL changes to `www.example.com/subfolder/public`, but I would like that it doesn't change.

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ subfolder/public [NC,L]
```

### EDIT

This first .htaccess is used to redirect on subfolder/public, where there is an other .htaccess that makes all the works.

Here the code of the second .htaccess located on `www.example.com/subfolder/public/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Your current directive should work OK - it shouldn't redirect. Make sure you've cleared your browser cache. (Aside: You also don't need the `NC` flag)

Comment: Yes as I wrote it works fine, but url on broswer change, I want that redirect the request, without changing the url on broswer

Comment: If you are seeing a redirect (ie. the URL in the browser is changing) then _something else_ would seem to be doing this. The above directive alone can not do such a redirect. Do you have any other directives in `.htaccess`? Any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path? (Note the difference between an "external redirect" and an "internal rewrite". Your code shows a rewrite, not a redirect.)

Comment: Yes I've 2 different .htaccess, that one I posted on my `domainRoot` then on `subfolder/public ` I've an other .htaccess that redirect to the correct file and makes all the works, the firstone I use only to redirect the request to the second

Comment: That's the problem. Any mod_rewrite directives in `subfolder/public/.htaccess` will completely override (by default) the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file. So, the above directive is not even being processed. Add the contents of your other `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sorry, just realised what is happening. It has nothing to do with the second `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory, as mentioned in comments.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^.*$ subfolder/public [NC,L]
> ```

Since `public` is a physical directory on the file system, you need to include a trailing slash when internally rewriting to that directory. Otherwise, mod_dir is going to try to "fix" the URL by appending a slash - that is where the external redirect is coming from. (mod_dir implicitly triggers an external redirect from `subfolder/public` to `subfolder/public/`.)

So, try the following instead in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule .* subfolder/public/ [L]
```

The important thing is the trailing slash. The anchors (`^` and `$`) on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* are not required, since you are matching *everything*. And the `NC` flag is also not required for the same reason.

As always, make sure the browser cache is clear before testing.

---

**UPDATE#1:** The single directive above rewrites *everything*, including static resources, to the *directory* `subfolder/public/` which then relies on the second `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory to correctly route the request. In order to allow static resources to be rewritten correctly (represented in the HTML as root-relative URL-paths, of the form `"/js/myjs.js"`) then you will need additional directives in order to rewrite these.

For example, to specifically rewrite all `.js` and `.css` files to the real location in `/subfolder/public/...`

```
# Rewrite static resources
RewriteRule (.+\.(?:js|css))$ subfolder/public/$1 [L]

# Rewrite everything else to the "public" directory
RewriteRule .* subfolder/public/ [L]
```

**UPDATE#2:** To make the above more general, and to rewrite *any* static resource (images, PDFs, .txt, etc...) we can check for the existence of the file before rewriting, something like:

```
# Rewrite static resources
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.+) subfolder/public/$1 [L]

# Rewrite everything else to the "public" directory
RewriteRule .* subfolder/public/ [L]
```

This will mean that if any `.css` does not exist it will be passed through to `subfolder/public/`.

Comment: In this way it works in part, it load the index.php in public folder, without change the url (what I want), but now It can't load the static files in public folder (like: css, js, images)

Comment: Maybe it could work fine if I moved the static files on root folder, but I wouldn't change this structure if possible

Comment: What URL-path are you using for your static files? The above directive rewrites _everything_ to `subfolder/public/`, including static files if the URL-path goes from the document root. You may need to include a similar exception as used in your other `.htaccess` file, or include additional rewrites for the static files.

Comment: maybe I understand the problem, but I can't solve it. For static files I need to redirect to `subfolder/public/` + path of the static file request (ex. `subfolder/public/js/myjs.js` do you know how to do it?

Comment: So your HTML uses a _relative-path_ of the form `src="subfolder/public/js/myjs.js"`?

Comment: I'm using zend framework 1 and for the static files I used baseUrl method that get the request  to set url of the application, so using this configuration on .htaccess baseurl return www.example.com then concat the string of the static files, but it isn't corrent, It should contain also `subfolder/public/`

Comment: So, what is the actual URL-path that appears in the HTML of the page? Yes, whatever it is won't be correct, but depending on the exact path (root-relative, relative to the current file, absolute, etc.) will depend on what directive we need to include in `.htaccess`. Do you have any control to change these URL-paths? If these are relative to the current file then a `base` tag in the HTML might resolve this also.

Comment: In html page for static files the path that zend generete is: `/js/myjs.js`

Comment: ok it works fine! thanks! If I want to add also images I should put `RewriteRule (.+\.(?:js|css|jpg|png|gif|jpeg))$ subfolder/public/$1 [L]`?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. That is regex speak for `js` or `css` or `jpg`, etc. (`jpg|jpeg` can be combined into one: `jpe?g` if you wanted, but it's no different functionally.) If you had a lot of different (essentially unknown) static resources then you could implement a more general solution that specifically checks for the existence of the destination file before rewriting. I'll update my answer...