# RewriteRule -or Alias for document_root to subdurectory (not redirect) causes either `Bad Request` or `Internal Server Error`

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, alias

After exhaustive searching on SO and SF I find this rather concerning. All of the related answers causes Apache 2.4 to just break and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, it should be really simple.

For brevity, here is the code, though I've tested each separately, not all in 1 go as below:

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ .anon.dir/Repo/data/native/fuse/$1 [L]
    ## Bad Request

    RewriteRule .* .anon.dir/Repo/data/native/fuse/
    ## Bad Request

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /.anon.dir/Repo/data/native/fuse/$1 [L]
    ## Internal Server Error

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=TRGT:".anon.dir/Repo/data/native/fuse/index.php"]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:TRGT}
    ## Bad Request

    ## Alias / %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blah ... for vHost/apache conf only
    ## Internal Server Error - in htaccess
```

The actual code is in an `<if>` block, this exactly:

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /(^|&)ANONFUSETEST($|&)/">
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ .anon.dir/Repo/data/native/fuse/$1 [L]
</If>
```

I'm using Apache 2.4 and the target subdirectory has no `htaccess` in it, only an `index.php` file with  `<h1>It Works!</h1>` inside it .. This is on a shared host at a respectable hosting company, so there should be no funny business going on elsewhere.

Here are some useful links at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/956060/htaccess-nested-wordpress-folder-redirect) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488099/htaccess-redirect-to-subfolder-without-changing-browser-url) and
[one more](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/apache-alias-in-htaccess-mod-rewrite-question/2460) .. although as mentioned, it doesn't work .. or I'm doing something wrong, which is most probably the case.

Does it have to do with the `.` at the start of the path? -that it may be seen as "hidden"? .. I'm out of ideas :/

Any help will be appreciated and rewarded in kind, thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like a configuration- rather than programming-question (see [help/on-topic]) and the [tag:apache] tag description. Also check [ask] on descriptions like "it doesn't work", which aren't very helpful descriptions of the behavior you observe.

Comment: This is exactly why I've closed my previous account here; Olaf, if it was working I would not ask the question; yes it may very well be a configuration issue on the vHost, however, do you know what it is? Any insight on this issue would be appreciated as there are many of these questions that remain unanswered, closing this question will not solve the issue. Can you say for certain that it is config-related? if so, please provide the information and close the question, thanks.

Comment: If it is not "programming" related, then I guess you should also close all HTML and CSS questions and that StackOverflow should dismiss any of those questions and not support it at all, banned from here on? `.htaccess` rules are indeed fancy configurations, the same as any other; so close it as you wish, I will take it up with social media and cause a good public spectacle ... or you can just leave my question alone, it's not doing any harm.

Answer (score 0):

The working solution ***is*** rather simple, have a look, elaboration follows:

```
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.anon.dir/Repo/data/native/fuse/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /.anon.dir/Repo/data/native/fuse/ [L,QSA]
```

There seems to be some internal safety check that enforces a condition that makes sure the request is not the same as the target, additionally:

- the target-path **starts and ends** with a slash
- appending `$1` to the target will result in **404**, so `QSA` is used instead
- if you want to define the path once, you're out of luck, or so it seems

Assigning the path in a variable and using it this way will cause issues, like the following:

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /(^|&)ANONFUSETEST($|&)/">
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=TRGT:/.anon.dir/Repo/data/native/fuse/]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !%{ENV:TRGT}
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:TRGT} [L,QSA]

    ## result is `Bad Request`
</If>
```

If you know how to make this more "dynamic" e.g: using the path only once, then your answer will be preferable.