# apache htaccess rewrite but keep original url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I currently have this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

My goal is to redirect everything into the subdirectory /public without adding /public to the url.

Currently this:
https://somedomain.com/login

turns into this
https://somedomain.com/public/login

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488099/htaccess-redirect-to-subfolder-without-changing-browser-url seems similar.

Comment: You would seem to have another `.htaccess` file in the `/public` subdirectory - please include the contents of this second `.htaccess` file in your question. The code you posted would already do as you require, there is no redirect in what you have posted that would expose the `/public` subdirectory. So there must be something else that is causing this. Please confirm that you are seeing an HTTP external redirect and what is the HTTP status of this redirect?

Comment: _Aside:_ If you didn't have another `.htaccess` file in the `/public` subdirectory (that also uses mod_rewrite) then the above would trigger a rewrite loop (500 Internal Server Error) - which would not appear to be happening.